# Why this system of linear equations must be consistent

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Does anybody have any insite into why this system of linear equations must be consistent? I have read the directions on this page regarding asking a good question:
[How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960)
This question is from Anton, *Elementary Linear Algebra 9th Ed*.
I'm studying post grad cert in applied statistics. Doing a linear algebra subject next semester and just preparing for it.

$\begin{array}{1}a_{11}x_{1}+a_{12}x_{2}=0\\
a_{21}x_{1}+a_{22}x_{2}=0\end{array}$

What I said was that they both have different gradients,

$\begin{array}{1}x_{2} = \frac{-a_{11}}{a_{12}}x_1\\
x_2 = \frac{-a_{21}}{a_{22}}x_1\end{array}$

Therefore, they have to intersect.

I have taken some out of this question that may have caused confusion. Also the good fellows @John Gowers, @Li Chun Min, @irh, and @gt6989b have answered this question such that I understand more now how to approach such a question.
Can you please check this question now @amWhy, @Leucippus, @Shailesh, et al?

Thanks.
Bucephalus

Comment: We say a linear system inconsistent when there is no solution. But we can always name one solution, which is $x_1=x_2=0$.

Comment: Note that if $a_{11}=a_{21}$ and $a_{12}=a_{22}$ then the lines have the same gradient, but they still intersect - because they are the same line.

Comment: Thanks John that's a good one. Li, are you saying, we can just let all the coefficients equal 1?, then we have simply a trivial case of $x_{1}=x_{2}$?

Answer (score 2):

Geometrically, $a_{1,1}x+a_{1,2}x_2=0$ gives us a line through the origin, regardless of the coefficients $a_{1,1}$ and $a_{1,2}$. Clearly, any two lines passing through the origin must share at least one point: the origin.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's  a good one irh.

Comment: If you are happy with the solution, consider marking as the answer so the question is resolved.

Comment: I think I marked this one now. Still learning this website. Sorry about that. @irh

Answer (score 1):

If by saying a system is consistent, you mean that it admits at least one solution, then certainly $x_1=x_2=0$ is a solution.

Note that this is *not* necessarily the only solution though, since setting for example $a_{11} = a_{21}$ and $a_{12} = a_{22}$ yields essentially one equation in 2 variables with infinite possible solutions. However, if $a_{11}a_{22} \ne a_{21}a_{12}$, the solution $x_1 = 0 = x_2$ will be unique.

Comment: That's a great explanation thanks gt69. I only just realised that $a_{11}a_{22} \ne a_{21}a_{12}$ means that the equations are the same. Thanks for teaching me that also.